# Enterprise Library Logging Block - Locking the file and FTP fails to download it

Tags: enterprise-library, ftp-client, filelock

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 application, it uses Ent Lib 6 Logging Application block.

Details:

- My web site is hosted on shared hosting server.
- We use Filezilla (FTP client) to publish and download files/logs.
- Log file is created on server

Problem:

When I try to download the log file form the server using FTP I get error stating "550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

[image]

This is how my web.config looks

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>    
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>  
  <appSettings>
    .....
  </appSettings>
  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
          listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
          fileName="C:\ServerPath\Log\Log.txt" footer="" formatter="Text Formatter" header=""
          rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Day" timeStampPattern="dd-MM-yyyy"
          asynchronous="false" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
          template="{timestamp(local:M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff)} ({win32ThreadId}) ({severity}) {message}" name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  .....
</configuration>
```

As expected if I change my Web.config (on server)  file lock is released and then I can download it or if I wait long enough then also lock is released. But of-course none of this is acceptable. So is it possible to get logs real time from the server? Other option could be to use some other logging library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if you stumble upon this question this is what I have observed.

So after struggling for few days I have come to conclusion that there is no easy or straight forward way to resolve this unless I have a second URL where I can expose my log file thru browser. This works well but it does have associated security risk as anyone with the URL can view log contents.

The other solution is to ask your service provider to provide remote access to server this is more secure approach.